# how to use alternate vt100 character sets

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, ansi-escape, vt100

According to http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/alternate_charset/ <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>)</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> will make it so that a G0 set sequence table is used or something. http://www.vt100.net/docs/vt100-ug/table3-9.html seems to provide a description of the characters that should appear when this "table" is in use. eg.

```
<?php
echo "\x1B)0" . chr(0147)
```

...should result in a ± appearing on the console as I understand it. But no ± is appearing. Instead what's appearing is `g`.

So it's not entirely clear to me how to use this in a CLI environment to make ± appear.

Any ideas?

Comment: It probably will not work for Linux, because that part was broken long ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `(` instead of `)`:

```
<?php
echo "\x1B(0" . chr(0147)
?>
```

`(` sets the charset to be used in the default "g0" slot, whereas `)` effects the "g1" slot. The shift-in/shift-out escape sequences switch between the two slots.

In the mean time, I recommend you to forget about this legacy stuff and use proper stateless UTF-8 and its `±` sign.

Comment: lol you submitted an edit and I submitted an answer saying virtually exactly the same thing at virtually exactly the same time. UTF-8 is so much nicer than switching character sets and a new application should definitely use it. I think the majority of the escape sequences ought to be unused and you only worry about them if you're writing a terminal emulator that needs to support some legacy application.

Comment: Just thought I'd add that to undo it doing `"\x1B(B"` seems sufficient. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed one of the biggest points in using Unicode/UTF-8 is to be stateless, in which case switching back-n-forth between normal and alternate charset is obsolete. Emulators have to keep this feature to be backwards compatible, though. PuTTY was brave enough to refuse these in UTF-8 mode, which is technically probably much better, but causes headaches to many users.

See also http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#term